# Does $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x y \sin^2 y}{x^2 y}$ exists?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x y \sin^2 y}{x^2 y}$

Along $x =y$, it becomes

\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{y^2 \sin^2 y}{y^3} = 0.
\end{equation}

But along $x = y^3$,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{y^4 \sin^2 y}{y^7} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{ \sin^2 y}{y^3}.
\end{equation}
The limit is undefined.

This is what I thought, but using wolframalpha, it say the limit is $0$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your answer is right. The limit does not exist.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thanks!

Comment: WolframAlpha doesn't get limits and derivatives involving several variables (that includes complex derivatives) right sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right indeed

$$\frac{x y \sin^2 y}{x^2 y}=\frac{\sin^2y}{y^2 }\frac{y}{x}$$

and

- $\frac{\sin^2y}{y^2 }\to 1$

but

- $\frac{y}{x}$

has not limit.